# pns_confirmRegex of undefined

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, browser

I'm running a deployment to heroku, I'm unable to produce this locally, but I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pns_confirmRegex' of undefined
    at Object.i [as check] (h1.js:150)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (h1.js:62)
    at l (h1.js:48)
    at c (h1.js:48)`

Like I know there's an `undefined` item somewhere... and if you look at the sources, it's coming from something of `h1.js` .

I'm using react with some service workers in the front-end and they are all transpiled together with webpack. Does anyone have any idea what this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the stack trace very carefully and you should see that this probably has to do with https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/461.

I had the same error and uninstalled Honey. If you click on the links in the stack trace you should be able to look at the code and see a bunch of Regex selectors that Honey seems to employ.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Honey Chrome extension and cures the issue.  Thank you Yehuda M. Makarov

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)